# How to turn off Android Studio code analyzer?

Tags: android-studio

I didn't know that Android Studio could only handle 4000 lines of code in a single activity, otherwise, it would keep freezing whenever a new line of code is typed.

Now my single activity has been holding 9000 lines of code and this single important activity (that's why it has so many lines) is hardly updated for new features.

I know the reason it keeps freezing is that whenever a new code is being typed, Android Studio will start analysing every single line.

So, is there any way to turn off this analyser feature from Android Studio and then turn it on again when I have finished updating the activity?
Thanks!

Comment: File > Settings > Editor > Inspections. Here, you can disable various inspections or even disable them all by unchecking the box at the top.

Comment: I would advise to serious consider splitting your activity into smaller pieces. You can extract some stuff to util classes, if there are any adapters add them to separate files, maybe use fragments in separate files, or one of more viewmodels to extract there some logic... It can speed up development (less code scrolling) and ease the maintenance of the code and the health of android studio ;-)

Comment: @madlymad Hi there, thanks, those are useful tips to reduce code load in a single activity. I wonder can I move my dialogs to another activity? My codes are mostly dialogs.

Comment: Hi @dawis11 there are still options that need to be chosen, which ones that I need to choose to disable the inspection?

Comment: @Tommy there is always a way to split the code. But it may need serious refactoring. You can post a question with some snippets to provide suggestion on that. Dialogs can also be part of different file. Depending on the type of dialogs etc there are many different approaches you can follow, but some refactoring will required. Create a new question post a link and I can take a look ;-)